# Area enclosed by cardioid using Green's theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Let $$\gamma(t) = \begin{pmatrix} (1+\cos t)\cos t \\ (1+ \cos t) \sin t \end{pmatrix}, \qquad t \in [0,2\pi].$$ Find the area enclosed by $\gamma$ using Green's theorem.

So the area enclosed by $\gamma$ is a cardioid, let's denote it as $B$. By **Green's theorem** we have for $f=(f_1, f_2) \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2):$

$$\int_B \text{div} \begin{pmatrix} f_2 \\ -f_1 \end{pmatrix} d(x,y) = \int_{\partial B} f \cdot ds$$

So if we choose $f(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} -y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ for example, we get

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Area of $B$} &=& \int_{\partial B} f \cdot ds
\\&=& \int_{\gamma} f(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) dt
\\&=& \int_0^{2\pi} \begin{pmatrix} -(1+ \cos t) \sin t \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot\begin{pmatrix} \sin t ( 1 - 2 \cos t) \\ \cos^2t - \sin^2t + \cos t \end{pmatrix} dt ,\end{eqnarray}$$

which I guess we can evaluate but if I keep going, this will become very nasty and tedious.

There must be a nicer way to do this. Please help me see it.

Comment: In cylindrical coordinates this is the area given by
$$
0\leq r(\theta)\leq1+\cos(\theta).
$$
Integrating we get
$$
A = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1+\cos(\theta)}r\ drd\theta,
$$
which is pretty easy to evaluate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current approach seems reasonably efficient to me: From this point, if you expand out the dot product, you'll get just three terms, each of them manageable integrals involving sines and cosines. You can handle parts of the integrals quickly using the fact that the interval has length $2\pi$, which is the period of the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions that occur.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, it's better to use $$\frac12\int_{\partial B}(-y\,dx+x\,dy)$$ whenever trig functions are involved. That will give a simpler expression once you use standard trig identities.

Comment: It's more straight forward in this particular case to do the area integral directly in polar coordinates: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1+\cos\theta} r\,drd\theta.$$